# Odd syntax in API "String::concat"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was looking at some of the changes made to the Java SE API with 1.8, and I when looking at the new method  [Map.merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) it shows an example of how to use it with the line

```
map.merge(key, msg, String::concat)
```

I understand how to use a lambda expressions to create anonymous functional interfaces, but this seems to use a method as a BiFunction. I like to understand and use obscure java syntaxes, but I can't find any mention of this one anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

`String::concat` is a reference to the `concat()` method of the String class.

A `BiFunction` is a functional interface with a single method `apply` that accepts two parameters (the first of type `T` and the second of type `U`), and returns a result of type `R`
(in other words, the interface `BiFunction<T,U,R>` has a method `R apply(T t, U u)`).

`map.merge` expects a `BiFunction<? super V,? super V,? extends V>` as the third parameter, where `V` is the value of the `Map`. If you have a `Map` with a `String` value, you can use any method that accepts two `String` parameters and returns a `String`.

`String::concat` satisfies these requirements, and that's why it can be used in `map.merge`.

The reason it satisfies these requirements requires an explanation :

The signature of `String::concat` is `public String concat(String str)`.

This can be seen as a function with two parameters of type String (`this`, the instance for which this method is called, and the `str` parameter) and a result of type String.

Comment: Method references are described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Thanks. I kinda guessed that. I was wondering what are the rules for using a method as a functional interface?